# SageMaker provisioned endpoint concurrent invocation limit

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

On [Amazon SageMaker endpoints and quotas](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sagemaker.html) I read that Maximum concurrent invocations per endpoint variant is 200 in SageMaker Serverless Inference.
Does this limit applies to provisioned endpoints? If not, what's the equivalent limit for this case?

We are reaching up to 605 Invocations/Second (see graph below) on our provisioned endpoint (3 ml.m5.xlarge), and yet not seeing any throttling / failure on client side. Are we missing something?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Serverless inference, SageMaker hosting (AKA: real-time endpoint), have no predetermined max invocations/sec. The max throughput will depend on the invocation payload and processing and the specific instance type.

Having said that, there *could* be service side limits when you'll reach more than 10K/sec. So if you expect more growth, you could:

1. Run a scale out experiment, to [stress test](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/endpoint-scaling-loadtest.html) the system and see where it breaks and at what invocations/sec.
2. Contact your AWS Account team (if you have one) and discuss with an AWS solutions architect. If not, contact AWS support.